# Python: Storing earliest occurrence of a character's index, instead of the last

Tags: string, python-3.x

I'm writing a function to check if the distance between 'a' and 'b' in a string is 3 using the following function. For the input string "Laura sobs", the value of 's' is stored as 1(earliest occurrence of 'a') instead of 4(the last occurrence of 'a') and I get the wrong output. How do I fix this?

```
def ABCheck(str): 
    for i in str:
        if i == 'a':
            s = str.index(i)
        elif i == 'b':
            t = str.index(i)
            # print (b)
    return (abs(s-t)==4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `enumerate` to loop over the string while keeping an index around. Then, when you find an 'a', just check if the character 3 places further on is a 'b'.

```
def abcheck(s):  # Don't use str, it's the name of a builtin
    for idx, c in enumerate(s[:-3]):  # No need to iterate over the last part
        if c == 'a' and s[idx+3] == 'b':
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks @RemcoGerlich, It worked when I used 'enumerate(s)' but didn't work with ' enumerate(s[:3])'. Could you explain this part? And what did you mean by 'No need to iterate over the last part'? Yeah, I don't use 'str' as a variable name, it's from the website :)

Comment: I meant `-3`. Because if you find an 'a' in one of the last three characters, there isn't enough room for there to be a 'b' three characters later, so no need to check for them (otherwise you have to make sure you don't index after the end of the string).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I learnt how useful enumerate function can be :) just a minor correction, it should be '4' instead of '3' and added s[idx-4] == 'b' with an 'or'

Comment: Well, that depends on your definition of distance. In the string "axxb", I'd say the distance between a and b is 3, and then the number should be 3. Don't see what you mean with 'or'.

Comment: I mean, I used this: if c == 'a' and (s[idx+4] == 'b' or  s[idx-4] == 'b'):

Comment: Ah, I didn't know it also counted if b occurred before a. But that is a bug: if `idx-4` becomes negative, then it counts from the the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems very hard-coded to only check for the instance where the difference is 3 and the letters have to be 'a' or 'b' instead of input in from somewhere.

If you are a beginner trying to build something, I don't think this is good practice. However if you are very sure that is what you want (a function that only handles this specific case), then by all means:

```
def ABCheck(str): 
    s = -1
    t = -1
    for i in str:
        if i == 'a' and s == -1:
            s = str.index(i)
        elif i == 'b' and t == -1:
            t = str.index(i)
            # print (b)
    return (abs(s-t)==3)
```

Just initialize both to -1 and check for it. Once their values have been overridden the first time, they will no longer update.

Edited:

```
def ABCheck(string): 
    s = -1
    t = -1
    for i in string:
        if i == 'a' and s == -1:
            s = string.index(i)
        elif i == 'b' and t == -1:
            t = string.index(i)
            # print (b)
    return (abs(s-t)==4)
```

It doesn't work because your code (which I copied) originally used str which is a reserved keyword.

Comment: No, it doesn't work! It's a code challenge from coderbyte where it has to specifically check if the difference between the positions of 'a' and 'b' in a string is 3, that's why it's hard-coded :)

Comment: @Sri It doesn't work because your code (which I copied) originally used str which is a reserved keyword. You could really just have tried to debug it yourself, it wasn't anything major. Additionally, next time ensure that the code you upload actually works like how you described it.